# spring data jpa with hibernate 6 - why the jpa save() method do insert when I try to update a non-existing record?

Tags: java, hibernate, methods, spring-data-jpa, deprecated

I have a "Test" entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TEST")
@lombok.Data
public class Test { 
    
    @Id
    @jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue(generator = "test_id_gen_key")
    @org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator(name="test_id_gen_key", type=org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator.class)
    @Column(name="id", nullable = false)
    private Integer id;
    
    @Column(name="name", nullable = true, length = 10)
    private String name;
    
}
```

And the TestRepository:

```
@Repository
public interface TestRepository extends JpaRepository<Test, Integer> {

}
```

When I try to do a update in TestService like this:

```
var test = new Test(10, "any name");  // the id value : 10 does not exist in the databse 

testRepository.save(test);
```

Then the hibernate execute the merge() method:

1. query the database with the id value ： 10；
2. got nothing from step 1, then it execute an insert sql to generate a new record.

But what I want in this situation is to throw a exception, the CrudRepository#save method also said "also thrown if the entity is assumed to be present but does not exist in the database" :

```
    /**
     * Saves a given entity. Use the returned instance for further operations as the save operation might have changed the
     * entity instance completely.
     *
     * @param entity must not be {@literal null}.
     * @return the saved entity; will never be {@literal null}.
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException in case the given {@literal entity} is {@literal null}.
     * @throws OptimisticLockingFailureException when the entity uses optimistic locking and has a version attribute with
     *           a different value from that found in the persistence store. **Also thrown if the entity is assumed to be
     *           present but does not exist in the database**.
     */
    <S extends T> S save(S entity);
```

What is the best way to handle this situation?

I extend the SimpleJpaRepository implementation and add a update method to call the org.hibernate.Session#update() method, it works as I expected, but the method is deprecated already, I dont think its a prefect solution:

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public T update(T entity) {     
        session().update(entity);
        
        return entity;
    }
```

Comment: Never use @lombok.Data because equals will be wrong

Comment: @SimonMartinelli yes you are right, but its not important in this question.

Answer (score 1):

This is implemenation for JPA save function:

```
    @Transactional
    public <S extends T> S save(S entity) {
        if (this.entityInformation.isNew(entity)) {
            this.em.persist(entity);
            return entity;
        } else {
            return this.em.merge(entity);
        }
    }
```

So, as you can see, JPA do check if entity is existing or not.
If yes, then it will update, otherwise JPA will insert a new record. If you don't want to insert if not exist, you can call findById() first, throw exception if entity not exist, then call save() after that. Please don't try to modify default behavior of JPA as it can cause more issue in the future.

Comment: thx to @Long, its good enough to solve my problem, in fact, I could rewrite the save method as：
                 ID id = (ID)entityInformation.getId(entity);  
    
  Optional<T> persistenceOptional = this.findById(id);
  if (persistenceOptional.isEmpty()) {
   throw new StaleObjectStateException(entityInformation.getEntityName(), id); 
  }
                // do the update
But I still think there is a possible best way to handle this, any more idea?

Comment: Still not get what you're trying to do. If you modify like that, how can you insert new record from now on?
You can extend your repository with a custom interface that contains custom function called updateIfExist(), then you can implement that function with your logic. Throw error when entity not exist... etc. 
For update() function of JPA, just leave it as it is.

Comment: I meant the implementation code seems a little strange. It's need to query at first before update, however I dont want do like that, its not so elegant...

Answer (score 0):

You should implement `org.springframework.data.domain.Persistable`

**Explanation**:
Spring Data only has a single save method, but underneath it needs to do either persist or merge, as you can see in the save implementation. This is only an issue if you assign the primary key in code. If JPA assigns it, using an IDGenerator, you don't need to do anything, because spring data sees that the ID is null, so it will call persist.

Spring Data designed an extension point for this specific usecase, so we can tell the framework if the entity is new or old, and the id is not null. The solution is to implement the `org.springframework.data.domain.Persistable<ID>` and override the `isNew()` method.
When you have an unmanaged Entity, and call save it, Spring data will forward to persist, as detailed in the save method. If you have an unmanaged entity, that is not new, Spring data will merge the entity, as the JPA spec specifies.